# When Java class is instance of Serializable

Tags: java, class, junit, instance, serializable

I wonder when Java Class is instance of Serializable. As I know class is serializable only if it implements Serializable interface. 
I'm trying to use junit to generate entity class (from some kind of template) and check if it is serializable.

My generated class (which does NOT implement Serializable) looks like:

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
@Table( name = MyTestTableDto.TABLE_NAME )
public class MyTestTableDto 
{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "MY_TEST_TABLE";

    public static final String COLUMN_MY_ID_FIELD = "MY_ID_FIELD";
    public static final String FIELD_MY_ID_FIELD = "myIdField";

    @Id
    @Column( nullable = true, length = 14, name = COLUMN_MY_ID_FIELD )
    private Long myIdField;

    public Long getMyIdField()
    {
        return myIdField;
    }

    public void setMyIdField( Long aMyIdField )
    {
        this.myIdField = aMyIdField;
    }

}
```

Test is below:

```
 File generatedFile = new File( GEN_OUTPUT_DIR, File.separator + className + ".java" );

 assertTrue( generatedFile.getClass() instanceof Serializable ); //returns true
```

The result suggest that my generated class is instance of Serializable. My question is why? I think if it does not implements Serializable it should not be instance of it. I searched for an answer but I couldnt find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this:

```
File generatedFile = new File(...);
```

This created an **instance** of the class `File`.

```
generatedFile.getClass()
```

This got the `Class` object for the `File` object, an object of type `Class<File>`

The [documentation of File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) describes the class:

> All Implemented Interfaces: **Serializable**, Comparable

If you'd like to achieve that you want to parse a java source file to see if it implements Serializable, you should get an appropriate tool for this, build the abstract syntax tree of the file in question, and extract the information from there.

Or you could just do it like this, using the [isAssignableFrom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) method of the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class:

```
public boolean checkSerializable(Class<?> classToCheck) {
    return Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(classToCheck);
}
```

And then check the class itself:

```
boolean isSerializable = checkSerializable(MyTestTableDto.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you call instanceof on Class object, which is serializable.

getClass returns a `Class<T>` object, where T is the type of the class. Because Class is defined as

```
public final
class Class<T> implements java.io.Serializable,
                          java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration,
                          java.lang.reflect.Type,
                          java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement 
{
  ...
}
```

it's clearly serializable.

Comment: The others are right. In his test he instanciates an Object of Type File and checks if that instance of File is Serializable or not. He does not check his own implementation

Comment: @cheffe : ```generatedFile.getClass()``` returns a Class object. That specific Class object is tested with instanceof. The instanceof sees Class<File>, which is serializable, therefore it returns true. To test if the file is serializable, you need to type ```generatedFile instanceof Serializable```, not ```generatedFile.getClass() instanceof Serializable```.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
assertTrue( generatedFile.getClass() instanceof Serializable );
```

is returning `true`, because this will check whether the runtime class of this generatedFile Object is an instance of `Serializable` or not. And the class object is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the below call will return Class instance for `File` object, not `MyTestTableDto`

```
generatedFile.getClass()
```

(removed the wrong statement)